# How to subtract a value from a database field

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$show = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Coins FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username = '".$user."'; ");
```

I need to make a php page where, when it is opened, it will turn the value in the Coins field into the current value of the Coins field - 200. Any way how? Thanks

Comment: Your Query any Your requirement doesn't matched.

Comment: specify the code in which you are trying to do the above case ie, subtraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Leaderboard SET Coins = (Coins - 200) WHERE Username = '".$user."';");
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to just show -200 not update then use

```
$show = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT (Coins - 200) AS Coins FROM Leaderboard WHERE Username = '".$user."'; ");
```